# Delete a line of code on specific Wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website that is a few years old; the home page is being slowed quite badly upon load by a request for an image file that existed in an earlier build, but no more. The request leads to a 404 error and this happens before the page will load on the front end. To clarify this image has been long since deleted off the website, however the core code still requests it. Ive been able to find the line of code in developer tools on Safari but have had no such luck finding it on the Wordpress backend. How can I go about finding and deleting this line of code? Any help anyone could give would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

It is added like this via https://baseenterprisecentre.ie/wp-content/et-cache/5928/et-core-unified-5928-15898887434759.min.css:

```
.et_pb_row_5{background-image:url(https://baseenterprisecentre.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/baseGreen.png)}
```

For reference this is the website: https://baseenterprisecentre.ie
And this is the offending image:  background-image:url(https://baseenterprisecentre.ie/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/baseGreen.png)

thanks 
Jon

Comment: I think this image was set in the theme options because it is added via CSS that has been added dynamically. Did you go through the theme options?

Comment: What creates 'et_pb_row_*' - a plugin, a theme, a framework/lib?

Comment: Thanks for the reply jasie, I'd say your right about it being somewhere in the theme; I think when I was originally building the website it was used as a temporary placeholder but it was a while back now, I also thought it may be in the header or footer as it shows up on a few pages. To answer your question I have checked the theme options and I had deleted any custom CSS I had there about a week ago as I thought this was contributing to the load speeds. The 'et_pb_row' is theme specific I'm guessing; the site is built with DIVI from Elegant Themes hence the 'et'.